# Laravel Blade, Mix and SASS resource versioning sharing

Tags: laravel, sass, frontend, laravel-blade, laravel-mix

In my project, I use some resources (mainly images) in both SASS and Blade. Also, I have some resources only used in SASS, and some only used in Blade.

For example, I could use `mix('images/logo.png')` in Blade files, and `background: url('../images/logo.png')` in SASS files.

As for my directory structure, I did the following :

```
- resources
    - js
    - sass
    - images  // All images used by Blade, Sass, or both
    - fonts
```

In order to compile my resources and place them in the `public` folder, I use to following `webpack.mix.js` :

```
mix.copy('resources/images/**/*.*', 'public/images');
mix.copy('resources/fonts/**/*.*', 'public/fonts');
mix.version('public/images/**/*.*');
mix.version('public/fonts/**/*.*');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/js/vendor.js', 'public/js')
    .scripts([ // Old not ES6 JS
        'resources/js/tpl/core.min.js'
    ], 'public/js/core.min.js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .sourceMaps()
    .version();
```

In result, I get that URL in app.css :

```
background: url(/images/logo.png?0e567ce87146d0353fe7f19f17b18aca);
```

While I get another in rendered HTML :

```
src="/images/logo.png?id=4d4e33eae039c367c8e9"
```

They are considered as 2 different resources, that's not what I expected...

**Potential workaround**

I discovered that CSS files generated by SASS use a versioned URL even if I don't specify `version()` in `webpack.mix.js`. So I was wondering maybe I could use some trick, like this one :

```
const sass = require('sass');

// Custom SASS function to get versioned file name
// Uses Mix version md5 hash
const functions = {
    'versioned($uri)': function(uri, done) {
        uri = uri && uri.getValue() || uri;
        const version = File.find(path.join(Config.publicPath, uri)).version();
        done(new sass.types.String(`${uri}?id=${version}`));
    }
};

mix.sass('resources/sass/all.scss', 'public/css', { 
        sassOptions: {
            functions
        }
    })
    .options({ // Do not process URLs anymore
        processCssUrls: false
    });
```

And use it in SASS like so :

```
background-image: url(versioned('/images/logo.png'));
```

But this solution have a lot of drawbacks, I am obliged to use the `versioned` function every time, my source code won't work easily in other projects without the `webpack.mix.js` function, and I have to edit every files that I use in my resources folder to use the function.

**Other solution?**

I think the source of my problem could come from the way I structured my files, I have a `resources/images` folder which contains images used by SASS but also used by Blade.
Images used in SASS will be copied to `public/images` because that's the way SASS works with webpack, and these images will also be copied a second time because I used `mix.copy()` (because I need the other files to be inside the public folder in order to be accessible in Blade/HTML).

I'm pretty sure I'm mistaking somewhere, I looked over the internet for a proper way to work with SASS and Blade resources in Laravel but I didn't find anything relevant.
Maybe I should consider another file structure ? But which one ?

Comment: I want to give my own thoughts while I'm also facing the same issue.

Laravel Mix handles .blade and CSS/JS files differently. You won't get the same hash for your logo image as for .blade assets it uses ```mix.version()``` and for CSS files, there's its own file loader with its own hashing function. It has nothing in common with file structuring.

Your proposed workaround seems to be a nice option, I don't think there's a native solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I discovered that CSS files generated by SASS use a versioned URL even if I don't specify version() in webpack.mix.js.

Rewriting `url()` within stylesheets is a [webpack feature](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/5.0/css-preprocessors#css-url-rewriting), it appends the computed MD5 hash of the file to the URL. `mix.version()` on the other hand generates a different hash thanks to [those lines:](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/blob/v5.0.0/src/File.js#L162-L174)

```js
/**
 * Read the file's contents.
 */
read() {
    return fs.readFileSync(this.path(), 'utf8');
}

/**
 * Calculate the proper version hash for the file.
 */
version() {
    return md5(this.read()).substr(0, 20);
}
```

Laravel Mix reads the file as a string (not as a buffer), hashes it and extracts only the first 20 characters. I can't figure out a simple way to override this behavior, a quick and dirty workaround is the redefine the `hash` function:

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
let md5 = require('md5');
let fs = require('fs-extra');

Mix.manifest.hash = function (file) {
    let f = new File(path.join(Config.publicPath, file));

    let hash = md5(fs.readFileSync(f.path()));

    let filePath = this.normalizePath(file);

    this.manifest[filePath] = filePath + '?' + hash;

    return this;
}
```

A better way is to [extend Laravel Mix](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/5.0/extending-mix) and define your own `versionMD5()` method, you might copy some code from [this extension](https://laravel-mix.com/extensions/lmvh).